# How to check if a react component contains exactly three inputs in testing

Tags: testing, jestjs

I was creating rests for a component and I just wanted to test if that component contains exactly three input fields to achieve that I have this code so far `expect(wrapper.find('Input').exists());`

Answer (score 0):

Use `toHaveLength()`

`expect(wrapper.find('Input').toHaveLength(3));`